# Is it standard to save Photoshop Editing capabilities for PDF?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf

Is it poor judgement to preserve photoshop editing capabilities if creating a PDF for a client? I'm wondering if it comes across as unprofessional or whether it might be a courtesy to save the document this way.

Comment: Chances are 99.9% of client would never even know. I personally never give clients workable files unless they pay for them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't as you never know who could be editing it in the future, you need to maintain design brand value. It also allows for potential work in the future as you are the original creator who can amend.

I'm not sure what the copyright law is in your country, but unless your contract is a buyout ect then you will own rights to the work. Most of it will come down to what the context of the piece is and how you feel about the client.